# Progressive ID number based on the same value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have in a Google spreadsheet in Col B some values that I would assign a progressive number in Col A.
In particular I would that this **progressive number** must be assigned to the unique value in Col B.

**Desidered Output:**

1 | dog 
1 | cat 
2 | dog 
2 | cat 
1 | mouse 
2 | mouse 
3 | dog 
3 | cat 
...

Comment: If your data sits in `B1` and down, you could use: `=COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B1)` in `A1` and down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data starts in row 2, see if this works

```
Arrayformula(if(len(B2:B), countifs(B2:B, B2:B, row(B2:B), "<="&row(B2:B)),))
```

[image]